# DB2: How to backup a DB2 database?

Tags: database, db2, backup

DB2 v10.1 database on WINDOWS 7.

Can somebody share about creating a database backup of the DB2? I could not find detailed instructions.

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter

Comment: might like to have a glance at db2 features - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/db2-9-5-backup-and-recovery-basics/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the documentation?  Perhaps the "Data Recovery Reference"?

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006150.html

Answer (score 2):

In a db2cmd window type \DB2 HELP BACKUP\ for more complete command syntax.  The simplest form of the command is

```
DB2 BACKUP DATABASE <database name>
```

Optim Studio in 9.7 and 10.1  and Control Center in 9.7 have GUI's to assist with these tasks as well.

Answer (score 0):

For a local backup you can use a simple command line command also provided in the other answers:

```
db2 backup database <name>
```

If you want a more automated solution that's more for "enterprise" then you should look into IBM Tivoli Storage Manager for example. DB2 supports making backups to network storaged TSM on the fly with incremental backups without disrupting the local database from working. I.e. you can run queries while the backup is running.

For TSM you need log archiving enabled on the database, you can do that with command should be:

```
db2 update db cfg using LOGARCHMETH1 TSM
```

After you have enabled log archiving you can create a backup script and schedule it:

```
set DB2INSTANCE=DB2
"C:\IBM\ProductName\db2\BIN\db2cmd.exe" /c DB2.EXE backup db WPSDB user <DOMAINUSERNAME> using <DOMAINUSERPASSWORD> online use tsm include logs
```

Here's a link to a full tutorial: http://www.codeyouneed.com/db2-backup-using-tsm/

Answer (score 0):

**For detailed step by step guide to configure DB2 backup, you can refer:**

[DB2 v9.7 on AIX(x64) backup configuration for TSM v7.1](http://tsmtools.co.nf/db2_bkp.html)

Every step form planning, preparation and execution is explained with diagrams.

Basic steps are:

1. Download Appropriate TSM API 32/64 bit based on db2level from passport advantage
2. Extract TSMCLI_AIX.tar
3. Login as root and enter "SMITTY INSTALL"
4. Select required components:

   **tivoli.tsm.client.ba.64bit**, 
   **tivoli.tsm.client.api.64bit** etc.

If not using TSM client GUI then no need to install

```
Tivoli.tsm.client.jbb.64bit
Tivoli.tsm.filepath
```

5. Now apply steps mention in the link as example to configure for File level and DB2 level backup as per your environment.

Answer (score 0):

For offline backup you need to disconnect all clients and deactivate the database

```
db2 force applications all
db2 connect to database xxx
db2 quiesce database immediate
db2 terminate
db2 deactivate database xxx
db2 backup database xxx to ....
```